# awk gsub messing up format

Tags: shell, awk, gsub

I am trying to replace 2 columns that meet a specific criteria within a pdb by using a bash script that runs an awk file within it (the bash script has another purpose, and the awk file is for code separation). When I run the script without setting OFS, the lines with string replacements do not have enough spacing. When I set `OFS="\t"` the spacing is way too much (relative to the unchanged lines). Why is it changing the formatting for the entire line when only a string operation is performed?

Here is myScript.sh

```
(some unrelated grep stuff)
awk -f ./myAwkScript.awk 4HKD.pdb.bk > 4HKD.pdb.bk.gen
```

Here is myAwkScript.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk 

BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{ if( $1=="HETATM" && $4=="MSE" ) { 
        gsub( /MSE/, "MET", $4 ); 
        gsub( /HETATM/, "ATOM", $1 );
  }
  print;
}
```

Here's what the output looks like, so you can see what it does with tabs

```
ATOM    127  OE1 GLN A 449      -4.056  11.297 119.695  1.00 20.83           O  
ATOM    128  NE2 GLN A 449      -1.948  10.876 120.359  1.00 14.98           N  
ATOM    129     N       MET     A       450     -4.523  16.830  119.280 1.00    14.88   N
ATOM    130     CA      MET     A       450     -5.537  17.804  118.911 1.00    15.65   C
ATOM    137  N   ARG A 451      -3.902  19.530 119.337  1.00 15.80           N  
ATOM    138  CA  ARG A 451      -3.228  20.800 119.118  1.00 15.54           C  
ATOM    139  C   ARG A 451      -2.430  20.827 117.826  1.00 16.64           C            C
```

And here's what it looks like without changing OFS

```
ATOM    127  OE1 GLN A 449      -4.056  11.297 119.695  1.00 20.83           O  
ATOM    128  NE2 GLN A 449      -1.948  10.876 120.359  1.00 14.98           N  
ATOM 129 N MET A 450 -4.523 16.830 119.280 1.00 14.88 N
ATOM 130 CA MET A 450 -5.537 17.804 118.911 1.00 15.65 C
ATOM 135 SE MET A 450 -8.866 19.181 121.271 1.00 55.26 SE
ATOM 136 CE MET A 450 -7.749 20.188 122.510 1.00 28.83 C
ATOM    137  N   ARG A 451      -3.902  19.530 119.337  1.00 15.80           N  
ATOM    138  CA  ARG A 451      -3.228  20.800 119.118  1.00 15.54           C  
ATOM    139  C   ARG A 451      -2.430  20.827 117.826  1.00 16.64           C
```

Comment: Get the book "Effective Awk Programming", 4th edition, by Arnold Robbins and read at least the first couple of chapters to get an idea of how to write awk scripts as right now you are missing the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmodified line spacing is preserved.  If you add `$1=$1` before the print statement it will do.  Also since you're looking for exact match, there is no need for gsub. By the way you can rewrite your script as

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}
$1=="HETATM" && $4=="MSE" {
    $1="ATOM"        
    $4="MET" 
} 
{$1=$1}
1
```